# why ulimit restriction is affect by other processes?

Tags: linux, process, ulimit, thread

I have some processes creating large amount of threads (using python ray module), like 32 (proc) * 120 (thread per proc).

Then I found other processes would fail on creating threads while their nTH is actually small (like creating a new `ssh localhost` connection, or using `top` in other shell), far less than the typical restriction 4096 NPROC from `ulimit -a`.

I wonder if the `ulimit` is a user-scope restriction or process-scope restriction? If the latter, why would it be affected by other processes?

Comment: It's user-scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the main config file for limits (`limits.conf`) you will see the first column is domain. And in this column you can have: `*` (wildcard for everyone), `username` (for user limits) and `groupname` (for group to apply the limits).

So by default limits in Linux apply per user, not per process.

Comment: Thanks. Now `setrlimit` seems to work per process, but the default limit is user-wide, the combined result is a "boom" to other processes:(

Comment: @beantowel, right, `setrlimit` define the limits per resource.But mixing them can "unexpected behavior may occur. " (from man page).